# Swift - Improve computed properties in a class using Generics

Tags: swift, generics, frontend, computed-properties

I have this block of code in a view class I have:

```
private var notes: [String] = [] {
    didSet {
      if notes.count > 0, notes.count == (oldValue.count + 1) {
        tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 3)], with: .right)
      } else {
        tableView.reloadData()
      }
    }
  }

private var images: [UIImage?] = [] {
  didSet {
    if images.count > 0, images.count == (oldValue.count + 1) {
      tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 2)], with: .right)
    } else {
      tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }
}

private var urls: [URL?] = [] {
  didSet {
    if urls.count > 0, urls.count == (oldValue.count + 1) {
      tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 1)], with: .right)
    } else {
      tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }
}
```

It works fantastically, but I see this and straight away I want to improve it because it's almost exactly the same thing three times.. I've used some Generics in Java, and I've read through the documentation for generics in Swift but I can't quite get it to work. I want to eventually do something like

```
private var items: [T] = [] {
  didSet {
    if items.count > 0, items.count == (oldValue.count + 1) {
      tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 1)], with: .right)
    } else {
      tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }
}
```

so that I could keep it all in one section. Is this possible? I'm still quite the newbie so I appreciate any help even if this is a simple question to you :)

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated but the check `notes.count > 0` is redundant. If the second check succeeds `items` is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this with a simple function

```
private func updateTable(count: Int, oldCount: Int, section: Int) {
    if count > 0, count == (oldCount + 1) {
        tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: section)], with: .right)
    } else {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This would simplify the code to

```
private var notes: [String] = [] {
    didSet {
        updateTable(count: notes.count, oldCount: oldValue.count, section: 3)
    }
}
```

Another option is to pass the arrays

```
private func updateTable(array: [Element], oldArray: [Element], section: Int) {
    if array.count > 0, array.count == (oldArray.count + 1) {
        tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: section)], with: .right)
    } else {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a very good answer, but note that in the original code, the `section` changes based on each variable. This actually makes a much stronger case for your function-based approach, but it would be helpful to show that. Also, there's no need to pass `Array<Any>` (it may work, but it'll force an unnecessary copy if it does). You'd want to make `updateTable` generic: `func updateTable<Element>(new: [Element], old: [Element], section: Int)`.

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks for pointing out that section was changed, I completely missed that. And you're right that a generic solution is better for the array version.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you're having here is that, unlike many languages, in Swift the Array type is a Generic itself.  You could put the array in a wrapper struct, generic over T, which will allow you to implement the setter.

```
struct MyArray<T> {
   var items: [T] = [] {
      didSet {
         if items.count > 0, items.count == (oldValue.count + 1) {
            //something
         } else {
            //something else
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You could then wrap all the common methods if you so wished, or write an Iterator and conform to Sequence to get all the default methods.
Whether this is worth the overhead of dealing with the wrapper I'll leave up to you ;-)

Comment: Ah thanks! Did not know about Arrays being a generic, thank you! :)